# Flutter - How can I dismiss SelectionControls when scrolling?

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I am using SelectableText inside SingleChildScrollView.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: SelectableText(loremipsum),
  ),
);
```

In selectionControls, when I select the property named ToolBarItemControl.copy, chaos ensues. If you look at the [video here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCvVG.jpg), you can see the exact problem. How can I dismiss SelectionControls when scrolling?

Comment: Means if something is selected it should be unselected whenever scroll happens?

Comment: Yes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, simply add keyboardDismissBehavior to SingleChildScrollView. Like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: SelectableText(loremipsum),
  ),
);
```